# SQL find duplicate data

Tags: php, sql

can you help me to solve this problem.

im using PHP and MySQL.

i have sql query :

```
$qx=mysql_query("SELECT ORCASENO,ORORDNO From order_break WHERE ORCASENO='$bcode' AND ORDEST='$dest'");

 while($rx=mysql_fetch_array($qx))
        {
            echo $ORORDNO_rx= $rx['ORORDNO'];

        }
```

this code sample able to  generates two types of outputs.

ex: 1).
AAA
AAA
AAA
AAA
AAA

ex 2).
AAA
AAA
AAA
**BBB**
AAA

i need to generate error on **example 2** because it containing two/more different values for
 **$ORORDNO_rx**; like **BBB**

please help me to solve this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want the error to happen? Before you start outputting data? After you have already output the data?

Comment: Consider using PDO; your code is prone to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in way:

```
$qx=mysql_query("SELECT ORCASENO,ORORDNO From order_break WHERE ORCASENO='$bcode' AND ORDEST='$dest'");

$array = array();
while($rx=mysql_fetch_array($qx))
   $array[] = $rx['ORORDNO'];

if (count(array_unique($array)) > 1)
   echo 'Error';
else
{
   foreach($array as $value)
      echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query you could add count(distinct(ORORDNO)) in your select. Then do a check for > 1 in your php.